# Set maximum discount for magento shopping cart price rule

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to set a maximum amount for a shopping cart price rule in magento.
Here is what I am doing so far, it works correctly with one item, but wrongly with multi items:
listen event "salesrule_validator_process".

recalculate the percentage of a rule

```
protected function _getPct($address, $rule_pct)
    {
        $pct = $rule_pct/100;
        $maxDiscount = 3000; //the maximum value of the rule
        $items = $this->_getAllItems($address);
        $total = 0;
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $total += ($this->_getItemPrice($item));
        }


        if (($total*$pct)>=$maxDiscount)
        {

            return $maxDiscount/$total;
        }   
        return $pct;
    }
```

Has anyone been able to get around that? I'm using magento enterprise 1.13.0.2

Comment: Can you post the code from your observer method that is referring to _getPct()?