# How to make a promotional rule include conditions?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to make a promotional rule which includes the following conditions,

10% off on purchase of above Rs. 999 or more with a maximum discount of Rs. 500.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do that with something more than what Magento offers in its admin panel by default.

One way could be using an observer. You can first create the salesrule in your admin panel that applies 10 percent discount to purchase of more than 999, and then create an *observer* for your rule (for example this event: *salesrule_rule_save_before*) that controls the maximum discount threshold. You might find these links useful [1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method#customize_magento_using_eventobserver), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798069/creating-a-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento-automatically?rq=1), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017339/set-maximum-discount-for-magento-shopping-cart-price-rule).